# convert html table to csv

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback

I have a complex html table that I would like to export as CSV. To start with, I am trying to figure out if this can be done on server side. Table is created using the StringBuilder and spitted out in a div.

**Rule is that CSV has to be the created from the HTML markup in the browser not from model or data.**

To be able to create CSV on server side, I am unable to determine how to get/access the exact markup from the browser in one action methods after clicking the save button.

For now there is not much to the code itself as I am trying to just access the table in the controller. but here is what it looks like:
This is the request onclick for a button.

```
 $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "Application/Export",
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () { alert("Error!"); }
        });
```

Controller is empty for now:

```
   public string Export(string id)
    {
        //Convert to csv here
        return id;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why on earth would you be required to use the HTML table and not data from the model?  Please explain the reasoning behind this.

Edit: If you're screen scraping, then you'll need to grab the page via HTTP request, parse the HTML, then iterate over the parsed nodes while populating a CSV.

Comment: Screen scraping from a 3rd party app?

Comment: @Matthew It is a unique case, I agree. My HttpContext.Request.Form is empty, not sure why... any idea?

Comment: And I was hoping that once I have the <table> It would be easy to cast it to HtmlTable or similar control to allow easy access to rows and cells with correct rowspans etc.

Comment: @mvcstuff Try updating your question with the relevant code that's not working correctly.

Comment: Added some more data. There isnt much to it as all I am trying to do for now is access/find the html table in the controller.

Comment: I am posting the html markup to the MVC controller and use HTMLAgility pack to read the markup using XPATH

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jsoup: http://jsoup.org/ .